# How to add additional http header represents the auth principal from istio-proxy?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I have successfully followed this End-User Authentication Istio tutorial [here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authn-policy/#end-user-authentication) using Auth0 jwt token.

Now, I have a use case where I need to inject certain http header specifying the principal and its scope permission granted by that token. How to do that? And is there any guideline about it?

Comment: Have you checked this article?https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http_conn_man/headers